# Google sheets show only cells with text

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

Here is a link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LVB6T3cSwhjFuLJTkNWChs15_euX_CsUHD9YizEVV3k/edit?usp=sharing

I want to be able to show only the cells that have text in them.  The google form connected to this collects information regarding students who have missed assessments from grades 9-12. Unfortunately, google response sheet headers cannot be changed and are a reflection of the form itself.

The form has a separate section for grade 9, grade 10, grade 11, and grade 12 students. As you can see in the sheet, there are a ton of blank cells.  I would love to be able to have these show only cells with names in them. In the sample sheet, I created a sample of what I'd like to be able to see.  I only copied the grade 9 info from grade 9.  I did not copy the other information from the other rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I would approach this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pEZsmRjj291m6gBt-D2woJ2x8FpEKkaR9hlM3r5RidM/edit?usp=sharing

In general, you will want to leave the form response sheet alone as it will need to  house the raw data from your form responses. I've made tabs for each grade and used a query function to move data from the response sheet to the appropriate tab. The formulas are in the green cell in the upper left corner.

The structure of the formula I am using is as follows (I'm using the "Grade 9" formula as an example:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:E,Sheet1!F:AA},"select * where Col5 = 'Grade 9' ",1)
```

The portion in curly brackets `{Sheet1!A:E,Sheet1!F:AA}` is getting two ranges from the response sheet and treating it as a single query range. In this case I chose to do it this way because the first 5 columns of your response sheet `Sheet1!A:E` are common to all grades and then the second part of the range `Sheet1!F:AA` are the columns corresponding to the individual grade responses.

Column 5 is what differentiates the rows by grade. So I am filtering the query responses by the values in that column.

I wasn't sure how the "DIGITAL UPLOAD OF ASSIGNMENT/TEST (IF NOT A PAPER COPY SUBMITTED TO OFFICE)" columns were supposed to be grouped so you might need to adjust the range parameters if I have them associated with the wrong grades.

Comment: Wow! Awesome! I spent way too much time working on this over the past week. I should have reached out earlier. So appreciative of your help. It is exactly what I wanted. Will this continue to update the "Grade" tabs as new entries come in daily? "The Digital upload...." is exactly where I wanted it. This is critical for me bc this is where the link to the google doc will be found and I can just open it form there. Ill copy the doc, and try the query functions on the real doc with the private information. Ill let you know if things re working . Once again, huge thank you.

Comment: Me again :( , when I try to copy that formula 
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:E,Sheet1!F:AA},"select * where Col5 = 'Grade 9' ",1)                                    I get the error #VALUE! where it says "Unable to parse query string for Function Query parameter 2: No_Column; Col5.   I renamed my sheet to "Sheet 1 " as your query function has and everything else is identical to the shared document you used to create the sheet that was shared with me. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have the sheet name "Sheet 1" or "Sheet1"? the space there will make a difference.

Comment: That was it! Thanks once again. Slowly learning these functions in google sheets. Started the 30 day challenge by Ben Collins I think it is.....one new function per day. Hope to improve my knowledge and abilities soon! Thanks for the help and the quick response, so appreciated! THANK YOU

Comment: No problem! Also, just FYI, once you have all the formulas in place you can rename your result sheet and it will automatically update the formulas, that is, if you don't want it to be called Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

those `DIGITAL...` columns are inconvenient so the range needs to be split into chunks. add new sheet and paste this into A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet1!A1:G, FILTER(IFERROR(
 FILTER({(Sheet1!H1:AU1*0)/0;  Sheet1!H2:AU}, 
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!H1:AU),    2)=0)&" "&
 FILTER({(Sheet1!H1:AU1*0)/0;  Sheet1!H2:AU}, 
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!H1:AU)-1,  2)=0), "Student /accommodation"), LEN(TRIM(QUERY(IFERROR(
 FILTER({(Sheet1!H1:AU1*0)/0;  Sheet1!H2:AU}, 
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!H1:AU),    2)=0)&" "&
 FILTER({(Sheet1!H1:AU1*0)/0;  Sheet1!H2:AU},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!H1:AU)-1,  2)=0), "Student /accommodation"),,9^9)))>22), FILTER(IFERROR(
 FILTER({(Sheet1!AW1:BP1*0)/0; Sheet1!AW2:BP},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!AW1:BP)-1, 2)=0)&" "&
 FILTER({(Sheet1!AW1:BP1*0)/0; Sheet1!AW2:BP},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!AW1:BP),   2)=0), "Student /accommodation"), LEN(TRIM(QUERY(IFERROR(
 FILTER({(Sheet1!AW1:BP1*0)/0; Sheet1!AW2:BP},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!AW1:BP)-1, 2)=0)&" "&
 FILTER({(Sheet1!AW1:BP1*0)/0; Sheet1!AW2:BP},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!AW1:BP),   2)=0), "Student /accommodation"),,9^9)))>22), FILTER(IFERROR(
 FILTER({(Sheet1!BR1:CK1*0)/0; Sheet1!BR2:CK},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!BR1:CK),   2)=0)&" "&
 FILTER({(Sheet1!BR1:CK1*0)/0; Sheet1!BR2:CK},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!BR1:CK)-1, 2)=0), "Student /accommodation"), LEN(TRIM(QUERY(IFERROR(
 FILTER({(Sheet1!BR1:CK1*0)/0; Sheet1!BR2:CK},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!BR1:CK),   2)=0)&" "&
 FILTER({(Sheet1!BR1:CK1*0)/0; Sheet1!BR2:CK},
 MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!BR1:CK)-1, 2)=0), "Student /accommodation"),,9^9)))>22)})
```

**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fr_lob2ot5ITM-uluSCim2ETuGtzW6f1X-g2WgDr4so/edit#gid=2031447363**

[image]

Comment: Please, when you provide an answer also provide an explanation of what you are using to accomplish it.

Comment: I'll have a look shortly and provide feedback. Thanks in advance for your help!